# Webhook for Facebook Messenger doesn't validate Laravel5.4

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-5.4, facebook-messenger-bot, ngrok

So I was trying to make a Facebook chat bot using Laravel and ngrok. When I was asked to setup the webhook for the Facebook messenger API, I used ngrok to forward my localhost.

The problem is, it can't seem to validate the callback URL needed to setup the webhook. I used this link: https://b509de71.ngrok.io, generated by ngrok.

This is the error message I get:

> The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge,
>   expected value="211653810", received="\u003C!doctype
>   html>\n\u003Ch..."

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So, if anyone has the same problem, I should say that this apparently works fine. In my case, I had made an extra route, where my function lives, which I forgot to add to the URL. Silly me...
So this should validate and work just fine like this: https://b509de71.ngrok.io/testchat/